# How to copy the entire row of the active cell and paste it underneath with the formulas and data validation in shared workbook

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I needed to copy the entire active cell row and automatically paste it underneath the active cell row including the conditional formatting and data validation. However everytime I try to share the workbook, the row is pasted before the active row without the conditional formatting and data validation.

Current vba

```
Sub AddRow ()
       With ActiveCell
              .EntireRow.Copy
              .EntireRow.Insert shift = xlDown
        End With
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Offset the row you're inserting to by 1 to bump it down

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub AddRow()
   With ActiveCell
          .EntireRow.Copy
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftDown)
    End With
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```